# Rescaling pixels positions after augmented resolution of the movie

Tags: python, zooming, image-resizing, downsampling, rescale

I need help understanding the rescaling of coordinates pixel position (X,Y) of the center of an object in an image after rescaling from 64x64 to 640x640.
I explain: To use a deep learning tracking python code, I had to change the resolution of the film I have because the code doesn't work with such a small size, so firstly, I resized the film from 64x64x50000 to 640x640x50000 (50000 is the number of the images).
After calculating the objects' positions (X,Y), I retrieved a csv file in which the positions are in the format of 640x640, but I want to have this information in the original scale (64x64).

I believe that the cross product isn't really correct, I mean doing

```
newX = (currentX/currentWidth)*newWidth
newY = (currentY/currentHeight)*newHeight
```

It is not the correct way to downsample or have the real coordinates of the original images. When calculating the speed I found a shift and differents results comparing to another method I used.

[Here and example of the CSV file I retrieved and all I want is to convert the result from the 640 x 640 resolution to the 64x64 resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKN1w.png)

Could anyone help me understand or have any idea how can I get the true position, please?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77502826/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).